# JQuery plugin error : Object [object Object] has no method 'test'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, runtime-error

I wrote this in a separate .js file and attached to the HTML :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.test = function(){
        this.remove();
        return this;
    };
}(JQuery));
```

Then used it on another .js file on my html :

```
$("#table").test();
```

But this error appeared :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'test'
```

and I have no idea what's the problem !

Comment: well you either call test() before it has been registered or you never included the file.

Comment: are the two .js files you are using, included in the file?

Comment: At first include jQuery file before your plugin file, then correct `JQuery` with `jQuery` in your code

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I changed JQuery to jQuery and the code worked :)

Answer (score 0):

as Saber Haj Rabiee said, I changed JQuery to jQuery and the problem solved :)

Thanks Saber